# C++ functors to Java, overloading operator ()()

Tags: java, c++, interface, operators, functor

Suppose a simple example of functors in C++:

```
class Test2 {
    private:
        double a;

    public:
        Test2 (double a_) : a(a_){}
        double operator () () {return 10*a;}
};

template <typename Function>
double test ( Function function ) {return function();}

int main(int argc,  char* argv[]) {
    double a = test( Test2(5) );
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to implement this construction in Java (for example using the interface Functor)? Could you give me a short example? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's unclear what it is you're trying to actually *accomplish*. This seems like a simple case for a lambda.

Comment: @ chrylis Is it possible without a lamba? The function may be complicated...

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why not `Test2(5).test()`?

Comment: @ 4castle I am using the functor to "inject" a supplementary data necessary for computations. The operator ()() performs some complex matrix operations, matrices are constructed from this data. The code represents a significantly simplified example.

Comment: @ Jesper Thanks... Is there a different approach (natural to Java) to express this relationship?

Comment: @justik Use the built-in "at" functionality, with no spaces, which autocompletes. Your version doesn't actually notify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8, you can use the [`DoubleSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleSupplier.html) interface to get a `double` value from an object:

```
public class Test implements DoubleSupplier {
    private double a;
    public Test(double a) { this.a = a; }
    public double getAsDouble() { return 10 * a; }

    public static double test(DoubleSupplier ds) { 
        return ds.getAsDouble();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = test(new Test(5));
    }
}
```

If you aren't using Java 8, then you could just make your own interface to implement from:

```
public interface MyDoubleSupplier {
    double getAsDouble();
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, quite different approach than in C++ :-)

Comment: Actually, it's quite similar. Instead of using `()` to execute it, you use `.getAsDouble()` to execute it. Otherwise it's just slightly different syntax and different names for the same result.

Comment: Does it works for a static method analogous to getAsDouble or some additional parameters passed to this method (not involved in a constructor) ?

Comment: If you use a static method, you will no longer be able to use polymorphism to accomplish the task. In other words, you will have to hardcode all of the method calls. You will be better off keeping them as objects. And yes, you can add additional parameters, but you will not be able to use the `DoubleSupplier` interface. You will have to use your own custom interface. You can change all of these parameters as needed. Since Java relies heavily on object-oriented programming, you may want to use some tutorials so that everything makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to get exactly the same thing in Java, but the principle of what you're doing should be the same.

If you want a functor in Java that can be called like `functor_obj()`, that's not possible. Java doesn't allow operator overloading*, so that kind of syntax simply isn't possible.

However, Java 8 introduced the concept of "Functional Interfaces", which are defined as any Interface which has exactly one [abstract**] function. Any time you're working with a Functional Interface, it's instantiation can be replaced with a lambda expression.

```
Runnable run = () -> {System.out.println("Hello World (FROM THE SECOND DIMEN—I mean THREAD)");};
Thread thread = new Thread(run); 
//Also Equivalent to the two above lines:
//Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {System.out.println("Hello World (FROM THE SECOND DIMEN—I mean THREAD)");});
thread.start();
thread.join();
```

If you wanted to invoke this particular functor, you'd simply invoke it the same you would any other object that implemented an Interface:

```
run.run();
```

Because what Java Lambda expressions do is hide the implementation. The following code:

```
Runnable run = () -> {System.out.println("Hello World (FROM THE SECOND DIMEN—I mean THREAD)");};
```

Does the same thing as the Java 7 equivalent code:

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello World (FROM THE SECOND DIMEN—I mean THREAD)");
    }
};
```

So for your example, you'd probably write something like this:

```
public static double test(Supplier<Double> f) {//imported from java.util.function
    return f.get();
}
```

Which could then be invoked like this:

```
double a = test(() -> 25);
```

Which is equivalent to the code you wrote in your original `main` function. And if you need to store the functor for future use, you'd write it like this:

```
Supplier<Double> sup = () -> 25;
double a = test(sup);
/*sup can now be stored somewhere or passed to a different function.*/
```

---

* - I mean, Java DOES have operator overloading for `String` objects to allow the use of `+` to concatenate objects, but that's pretty much the only situation where it's used.

** - Java 8 also introduced "Default" methods to interfaces, which allows interfaces to have implemented methods. That might seem weird, until you realize it lets you write stuff like `public default void sort()` which can be added to `java.util.List<T>` to allow for all lists, which have accessors and removal operations, to be sorted using a common, generic algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There's no exact equivalent in Java, as there's nothing like overloading the meaning of `()` as you can do in C++.

Since Java 8 you can program in a functional style in Java, and there are a number of standard functional interfaces in the package `java.util.function`.

You could do something like this:

```
import java.util.function.DoubleSupplier;

public double test(DoubleSupplier supplier) {
    return supplier.getAsDouble();
}

public DoubleSupplier newSupplier(double a) {
    return () -> 10 * a;
}

// use it:
double a = test(newSupplier(5));
```